# Amplify Graphql Error: "Trying to redefine existing 'something' type" and tried to use an undeclared directive 'aws_subscribe'

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am getting following error as shown in image snapshot below. 
1st Error: Trying to redefine existing 'something' type. But i am only defining it once and i have made no changes to the file. This is autogenerated file from amplify add API command.
2nd Error: tried to use undeclared directive 'aws_subscribe'

I cannot understand what i am doing wrong.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem not exactly solved. But most probably right steps were not followed while adding api. Did again and everything worked fine this time.